# Issues with testing an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

I am having issues writing a test to verify that a value in my array is empty []

This are a couple tests I have tried

```
pm.test("Empty", function() {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.Big.Value).to.eql(undefined);
});

pm.test("Empty", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.Big.Value.length).to.eql(0);
});
```

This is my request response

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "date": "2019-09-20",
        “Big”: {
            “BigLabel": "Times",
            “Value”: []
        },
        "body": null
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "date": "2019-09-21",
        "Big": {
            “BigLabel": "Times",
            “Value”: []
        },
        "body": null
    }
]
```

Expected is a test that verifies that Value is empty

Comment: Surely this should be `jsonData[0].Big.Value.length` as the json data is an array of objects not an object.

Comment: Also, the `.Value` property on both your objects is never `undefined`, it is equal to an empty array, so that first test is going to fail even if you scope it properly in the manner @Deckerz recommended above.

Comment: @Deckerz thank you so much this worked.

Comment: Also if you post multiple it will need to be a for loop to test all of them `[0]` only does the first entry in an array @wyattbrandon

Comment: Yes @Deckerz i got the for loop working just by recognizing its an array of objects not just an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely this should be jsonData[0].Big.Value.length as the json data is an array of objects not an object. – @Deckerz answered this question but since it was a comment I could not close question. Thanks again @Deckerz